# How do I do @font-face antialiasing in Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-face

I'm embedding a font in Internet Explorer with `@font-face` and it works but is not antialiased. How do I enable antialiased rendering for embedded fonts in IE?

Comment: If the problem you're having is specific to IE 7/8 then [this article](http://allcreatives.net/2009/12/05/smoother-font-face-embedding-in-ie-7-8) may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are some known issues that you can work around.  If you [paste](http://www.webdevout.net/test/) some code or upload and link it, someone can probably point out just what the issue is.

(Couldn't merely comment, gj SO :p)